# How to track memory in heap area for a c program?

Tags: c, memory-management, data-structures, operating-system, profiler

I am trying to code a project which will track on heap area of c program, something like in memory profiler, on windows os, using dev cpp compiler,
what would be the steps for it?
thanks.

Comment: For which OS, which C implementation, please?

Comment: "How do I write a program to do x?" is not a good question for this site. Please read some of the [introductory pages](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: See our technical paper on "CheckPointer" for how to do this: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjjxr3QpuXOAhVCziYKHcCQB8UQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.semdesigns.com%2FCompany%2FPublications%2FCheckPointer.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFqQ1QjGm-OhSxNm0vZ3x0zZGPTWQ&sig2=2US-KmDmtW1iFFrXlUuT-Q  you can download Checkpointer itself from http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/MemorySafety/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at MemProf or massif.

Comment: I have already taken a look at them but there is no proper documentation available for it.